# Is DS28EC20 (20Kb 1-Wire EEPROM) a secondary address of I2C?

Tags: stm32, i2c, truestudio

I have a MCU ([nucleo64 L476RG](https://www.st.com/en/evaluation-tools/nucleo-l476rg.html_)), connected with I2C, and I2C is connected with [DS2482-100](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/DS2482-100.pdf) (Single-Channel 1-Wire Master), then to a [DS28EC20](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/DS28EC20.pdf) (20Kb 1-Wire EEPROM). I create project from stm32cubeMX and try to receive data from DS28EC20, there are two functions:

1. Receive in master mode an amount of data in blocking mode using @ref HAL_I2C_Master_Receive()
2. Read an amount of data in blocking mode from a specific memory address using @ref HAL_I2C_Mem_Read()

which one I should use? somebody mentions: "HAL_I2C_Master_Receive() used to communicate with those devices that do not have secondary address" so in my situation, does my I2C have a secondary address for DS28EC20?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the protocol for DS2482-100 seems not to be register or memory address based but writing commands and reading data, I would not use the *Mem* functions. What you need to do is to command the DS2482-100 chip ovef I2C to do 1-Wire memory access, which sounds overly complicated as STM32 would be able to talk 1-Wire directly.